# How to auto scroll when dragging mat tabs with cdk drag drop

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk-drag-drop

It seems that the cdk drag drop auto scroll is not working when used with mat tabs:

Here is the template

```
<div
  #docTabGroup
  mat-tab-nav-bar
  cdkDropList
  cdkScrollable
  cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal"
  class="example-list"
  (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
  (wheel)="scrollTabs($event)"
>
  <div
    #dragItem
    mat-tab-link
    class="example-box"
    *ngFor="let timePeriod of timePeriods"
    cdkDrag
  >
    {{timePeriod}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Dragging an item is not triggering the scroll. Is there a way I could implement that with tabs?

See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wpv2er-djgsig?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-horizontal-sorting-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-horizontal-sorting-example.html)

Comment: Same problem here, anything new on this?